# git push hangs only when connecting remotely

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am using Windows 10 Pro build 19041.388 on my server (desktop) and local (laptop) machines. I can connect perfectly over SSH on the same network and over the internet and git works as expected when in use directly on the server (desktop).

However, I am having trouble using some git commands on the server when I connect over SSH from the laptop. `Clone`, `add`, `commit`, and `pull` all work fine. But `git push origin master` just hangs and displays nothing. When I use `git push` on the server directly (not over SSH from the laptop), `git push origin master` successfully pushes the changes.

I recently updated to git version 2.27.0 on the server, could this have had an impact?

The output from `git config --list` is below:

```sh
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
credential.helper=manager
pull.rebase=false
core.editor="C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --wait
user.email=<my email address>
user.name=James <my surname>
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
```

I can provide any further information that may be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: So, if I understand right, you are self-hosting the remote repo rather than using something like Github? What service or tool are you using to host it? Or - do you just have the local repo on the "server", but you are connecting from the laptop to the server through SSH and issuing the git commands on the server, with the remote repo being elsewhere?

Comment: "I can connect perfectly over SSH on the same network" you do mean that you can ssh from your laptop on your desktop, right ? Have tried to copy {one large file,a bunch of small files} to your desktop using scp, and check the upload rate ?

Comment: Also : check if lfs could be the culprit. Clone your repo in a new folder, but *don't* setup lfs (remove the `filter` sections if they are present) ; on a test branch, create a commit (where you don't modify any lfs file ...), and push that test branch to your desktop.

Comment: @LightCC "Or - do you just have the local repo on the "server", but you are connecting from the laptop to the server through SSH and issuing the git commands on the server, with the remote repo being elsewhere?" This is correct. The local repo is on my desktop which I am connecting to from my laptop via SSH. I am attempting to push the commits to a remote respository hosted on github.

Comment: @LeGEC I have not set up lfs so I doubt this will be causing any issues. I will get back to you regarding the upload rate over scp but I don't expect this to be an issue.

Comment: Ah, `git push origin master` is always executed from the desktop, but in one case, you are using the desktop machine as a regular user, and in the other case, you are using your laptop, and ssh-ed on the desktop ? and in both cases, the remote `origin` is pointing at github ?

Comment: So many environment variables may change. Debug your ssh connection to github : run `ssh -v git@github.com` (or whatever ssh url is configured as your `origin`) in both setups, and compare the traces.